# ListView - animation when adding new row

Tags: android, listview, animation

I'm just trying to create animation for "add" method in listview. This works rly great, but animation is also triggered by removing item from the listview.

So

```
insert to index 0 -> "item 1" -> animation
insert to index 0 -> "item 2" -> animation
insert to index 0 -> "item 3" -> animation
```

result

```
item 3 
item 2
item 1
```

and now I want to remove "item 1" for example... and animation is of course triggered on index 0 (item 3 -> starting animation)

How do I know that this is a removing method?

```
private static void blink(final View v) 
{
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(300);
    animation.setStartOffset(20);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    v.setAnimation(animation);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            v.setAnimation(null);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_custom_row, parent, false);

    if(position == 0) // HERE some like isNewRow()?
        blink(view);

    return view;
}
```

Activity

```
adapter.insert("item", 0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Without another "list" object with the number of items to compare the adapter's getCount () I would not know exactly how to figure out whether you're adding or deleting it.